# Pandas Sort_Values generates error message:

Tags: python, pandas

I am a total newbie to python and pandas, although I am reasonably proficient at vba.
I am using python spyder2 (python 3.5) to import an excel file into a Pandas dataframe by read_excel(). This all seems to be working fine. After import I am sorting the data columns using sort_values.
`df.sort_values(['Part ID'],ascending = True, inplace = True)`
The part id column contains part numbers which can be strings (95%) and other part numbers that can look like integer's 123456789 or float 1234.65.
The error message is TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str().
I assume that this relates to mixed data types in the part id series.
I have tried applying .to_string and .astype(str) before the call to sort but to no avail.

Any help and explanation to aid my understanding would be appreciated.

full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar
df = pd.read_excel('Invoice Log (04-Jul-2015) Full Data Set1.xlsx', 0,header=0)
df['Invoice Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'])
df['Invoice Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Invoice Date'])
df['Month']= pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Invoice Date']).month
df['Year']= pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Invoice Date']).year
df.dropna(subset=['Part ID'],inplace=True)
df[['Part ID','Order Qty','Extended Price','Month','Year']]
df.sort_values(['Part ID'],ascending=True,inplace=True)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried .astype(str), did you get the same error or something else? And can you show how you tried that?

Comment: What is `df.dtypes`?

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()

Comment: I applied .astype in the following way:-

Comment: sorry, not used to this site: df['Part ID'].astype(str). error msg: TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()

Comment: applied .astype immediately before call to sort

Comment: Sorry that's hard to follow there. Can you edit your post to include that? `df['Part ID'] = df['Part ID'].astype(str)` works fine on my computer.

Comment: Hi Ayhan, thanks for the reply, you have just solved my problem.

Comment: df[['Part ID','Order Qty','Extended Price','Month','Year']]
df['Part ID'] = df['Part ID'].astype(str)
df.sort_values(['Part ID'],ascending=True,inplace=True)

Comment: NOT df[['Part ID','Order Qty','Extended Price','Month','Year']]
df['Part ID'].astype(str)
df.sort_values(['Part ID'],ascending=True,inplace=True) as I had written